# Родословная в Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Необходимо создать базу данных, в которой будет храниться родословная:

```
**Dogs**  
name  
age  
...

**Children**  
father  
mother  
child
```

Выходит, что первая таблица связана со второй аж 3 связями, но rails по умолчанию генерирует название столбца внешнего ключа dog_id. Можно как-то задать это название или можно что-то изменить в структуре базы данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в обеих таблицах хранятся собаки.
Значит таблица нужна одна.
Будет что-то вроде:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :father, class_name: 'Dog' # должен быть внешний ключ father_id
  belongs_to :mother, class_name: 'Dog' # должен быть внешний ключ mother_id
  has_many :children_of_father, class_name: 'Dog', foreign_key: :father_id
  has_many :children_of_mother, class_name: 'Dog', foreign_key: :mother_id

  def children
    children_of_mother.merge(children_of_father)
  end
end
```

Потом пишите миграцию на добавление внешних ключей, и всё.

Папка - `Dog.find(15).father`

Мамка - `Dog.find(15).mother`

Детки - `Dog.find(15).children`